# Login to OAM through OHS server redirect issue

Tags: http, httpserver, oam

I have an OHS 11g server setup on host1 with port 7777 and OAM 11g configured on host2 with port number 14100.

After I finished all the configurations. Now if I access host1:7777/oamconsole it redirects me to host2:14100 login page, then if I enter the correct username and password it logs in to OAM console with no problem and URL is back to host1:7777. Is there any way I can make the login page itself going through OHS server without redirecting to host2:14100 port? Thank you.

I have read a lot of documents and watched some videos, their environments seem to behave the same way but no one seems to care about the login page is still using host2:14100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out just update the Load Balancer HOST and PORT settings in oamconsole will make the login page use that HOST and PORT.